# How can chef run a command as a username?

Tags: linux, chef

In a Linux system, it is feasible to do

```
sudo systemctl start my_server
sudo -u ubuntu command ...
```

so that the command is run as the username ('ubuntu' in this case). However, and when I run chef with sudo privileges, my postscrip to replicate the previous commands reads:

```
systemctl start my_server
-u ubuntu command ...
```

Chef starts my_server without any issue but cannot interpret '-u' and stops with an error message. Is there any equivalent to "-u" or any other way to tell chef to run one line of a postcript as a user?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [script resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/script/) that takes a user property. That user property is the user to run the process as so in your case you'd have

```
script 'script-name' do
  user 'ubuntu'
  code 'command ...'
end
```

There's also a [bash resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/bash/) that works pretty similarly.

Note that if command is actually a script itself then you might want to look at the [execute resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/) instead.